# Calculating a rolling window of 8 hour size, using half hour increments in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, rolling-computation

I have a data frame with the following date column:

|  | scheduled_departure_utc | run_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-11 13:07:00+00:00 | 13149 |
| 128 | 2021-01-11 13:07:00+00:00 | 38138 |
| 1 | 2021-01-11 13:37:00+00:00 | 13153 |
| 129 | 2021-01-11 13:37:00+00:00 | 38139 |
| 2 | 2021-01-11 18:07:00+00:00 | 951600 |
| 130 | 2021-01-11 18:07:00+00:00 | 951600 |
| 3 | 2021-01-11 18:22:00+00:00 | 951780 |
| 131 | 2021-01-11 18:22:00+00:00 | 951780 |
| 132 | 2021-01-11 18:26:00+00:00 | 951201 |
| 4 | 2021-01-11 18:37:00+00:00 | 951802 |

I want to move a rolling window of 8 hour width over this data, and count the number of departures in that window. The only tricky thing is that I want each window to be calculated every half hour, so for example the first window might be from 00:00-08:00, then 00:30-08:30, then 01:00-09:00 etc.

Using pandas I can do the following:

```py
train_window = df.rolling('8h', on='scheduled_departure_utc').run_id.count()
```

However this gives me a confusing result. The data frame looks like this:

|  | run_id |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 128 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 129 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 130 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 131 | 8 |
| 132 | 9 |
| 4 | 10 |

I had hoped to have a data frame whose index is the date time at the start of the 8 hour window,  but instead the index is an integer, which I don't understand. In addition, because I specified `8h`, I suspect the window is being calculated every 8 hours instead of each half hour, but I'm not certain.

How can I count the events in a rolling window that has a different frequency from the size of the window, and then how can I get the results in a date-indexed format?

I'm on Python 3.9.1, and pandas 1.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to first [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html) the dataframe to have the same frequency as your wanted step-size (in this case 30 minutes).
Then you can use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with a window size of 16 (i.e., 8 hours).

```py
df['scheduled_departure_utc'] = pd.to_datetime(df['scheduled_departure_utc'])
df.set_index('scheduled_departure_utc').resample('30T').count()['run_id'].rolling(window=16, min_periods=1).sum()
```

Resulting pandas series:

```
2021-01-11 13:00:00     2.0
2021-01-11 13:30:00     4.0
2021-01-11 14:00:00     4.0
2021-01-11 14:30:00     4.0
2021-01-11 15:00:00     4.0
2021-01-11 15:30:00     4.0
2021-01-11 16:00:00     4.0
2021-01-11 16:30:00     4.0
2021-01-11 17:00:00     4.0
2021-01-11 17:30:00     4.0
2021-01-11 18:00:00     9.0
2021-01-11 18:30:00    10.0
```